# Keystore en Unity como cambiarla y poner una nueva en mi juego

Tags: android, unity3d, keystore

He comprado un juego de una persona que ya lo tenia en su tienda de google play y solo lo traspaso a mi tienda, este juego esta echo en Unity. El juego tiene su keystore que el dueño me dio, pero me gustaria cambiarlo con mis datos crear una nueva keystore.

He cambiado los Ids de Admob y el package store tambien, me gustaria saber si la keystore se puede cambiar tambien sin que afecte al juego que ya esta en mi tienda a la hora de crear un nuevo apk y actualizar el juego.

Answer (score 0):

Llena los siguientes datos en los campos:

```
keyStoreName - full path to the key store you want to use

keyStorePass - password for the keystore

keyaliasName - name of the key that you want to use

keyaliasPass - password for the key you want to use (if any)
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero me gustaria saber si ya teniendo una keystore del juego de la persona que me lo vendio al cambiar la keystore tendre algun problema a la hora de subir la nueva apk para actualizar, google play store aceptara este cambio o tendre problemas. Gracias

Comment: @Shivas no, si no tienes la keystore original no puede publicar actualizaciones de la app en cuestión

Comment: ok, estoy quiere decir que la app cuando se crea el programador genera una keystore y esta tendra que ser siempre la misma a la hora de actualizar dicha app, correcto?

Comment: @Shivas asi es, a no ser que cambies algo de la aplicación, crees tu keystore y empieces a subirla a playstore con otra keystore como otra aplicación aunque sea la misma.